# Proving measurability of a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider a Lebesgue-measurable non-empty set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. Let $Q(x) = \{x'\in X: f(x')\ge f(x)\}$ be the upper level set of $x\in X$. It is easy to argue that $Q(x)$ is a measurable set for every $x\in X$.

For $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, consider the set $S = \{x\in X: \lambda(Q(x)) = \alpha\}$, i.e., the set of points whose upper-level sets have measure equal to $\alpha$. Here $\lambda(\cdot)$ denotes the Lebesgue-measure.

I am trying to show that the set $S$ is measurable, and am requesting help with the same. If it helps, we can assume that $f$ is piece-wise continuous. Would greatly appreciate any hints!

Comment: Is $\lambda$ Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes. Edited the question with the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following, assuming $f$ is piecewise continuous:

1. if $f(a)\geq f(b)$, then $Q(f(a))\subseteq Q(f(b))$.
2. If $A\subseteq B$, then $\lambda(A)\leq\lambda(B)$.

Now for $r\in \mathbb{R}$ write $Q_r=\{x\in X\colon f(x)\geq r\}$ and let $b=\mathrm{inf}\{r\in\mathbb{R}\colon \lambda(Q_r)<\alpha \}$ and $u=\mathrm{sup}\{r\in\mathbb{R}\colon \lambda(Q_r)>\alpha \}$

Then $$S=\bigcup_b^u Q_r = \{x\in X\colon b\leq f(x)\leq u\}=f^{-1}[b,u]$$ is the inverse image of the measurable set $[b,u]$ and hence measurable.

Comment: edited to be much simpler

Comment: could very well be yes